# WebView.setWebViewClient Events Not caled in Android 4.4 devices

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-4.4-kitkat, webviewclient

in android 4.4 webview has changed, you can see it here: https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html

I am compiling my app with targetsdkversion and minsdkversion set to 9, so my webview is being launched in "quirks mode" as explained here: https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html

this quirks mode haves some problems with my webview because when i start my app in devices with lower android version it works perfectly but when i start it in 4.4 devices, none of the webview events are being called, pagestarted, pagefinished... etc none of them are being called....

i need that these methods get called because i need to override them for some reasons. ¿how can i solve it?

this is my code:

```
WebView adWebView = new WebView(this.ctx);

            adWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                }

                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(url.length() > 0){
                        if (!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://")){
                            url = "http://" + url;                      
                        }
                        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                        SectionManager.getCurrentActivity().startActivity(browserIntent);                                                                   
                    }else{
                        onAdFailed();   
                    }
                    //onAdFailed();
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                    onAdReceived(view);
                    view.clearCache(true);
                }               

                @Override
                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                        String description, String failingUrl) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    onAdFailed();
                }

            });         

            LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            adWebView.setLayoutParams(params);
            adWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            adWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            adWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            adWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

            adWebView.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: I've never had a problem with WebViewClient in KitKat. Are you changing anything in code based on OS version?

Comment: no, nothing, but i'm compiling with targetsdk 9, it is necesary for me, so webview is being executed in quirks mode